# How to compute Dedekind eta function efficiently?

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, computational-number-theory

According to wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function, Dedekind eta function is defined in many equivalent forms. But none of them is an explicit description (say in algorithmic format) on how to computing it. Where to find such one? Thanks!

Comment: There are some efficient Mathematica programs described in [a post on Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70140/number-of-divisors-visualized-with-the-qpochhammer-function-how-to-improve-perf)

Comment: Thanks! But it seems there is no an explicit description on how to compute Dedekind eta function on that page.

Comment: is this helpful for you? (also includes Pari code): [Evaluation of the Dedekind eta function](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masfaw/Chapter6.pdf)

Comment: Yes, it is very useful! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I find that the following paper presents an easier explanation on computing Dedekind eta function:

"Numerical Computation of $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1 - tx^n)$"
(by Alan D. Sokal @ arXiv:math/0212035)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Is not that paper by Chapman and Hart about evaluating $\eta$ at quadratic irrationalities only?

Comment: @LichengWang If I am not mistaken Sokal's approach is precisely what is done in that Mathematica.SE answer that I linked to

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე: Thank you very much for pointing out the relation between the above two refs.

Comment: Have you looked at the (C) source code for "eta()" in PARI/GP? It is called as ["trueeta(GEN x, long prec)"](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/Transcendental_functions.html).

Comment: @Somos: Thanks for your suggestion. I download PARI/GP source distribution. But the eta function in src folder seems just an explantion, instead of a source code.

Comment: @LichengWang Hi. Did you download the [PARI/GP tarball](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/pub/pari/unix/pari-2.9.4.tar.gz) which has the complete source code?

Comment: @Somos: Thank you very much! I found it in the file trans3.c. Thanks a lot! 

Another question: Does PARI/GP containing full package for isogeny computation? Any comments are highly appreciated!

Comment: @LichengWang You should ask your question about isogeny on the [pari-users mailing list](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/lists-index.html)

Comment: @Somos: OK! Thank you again for suggestions!

Comment: Pari/GP uses the `inteta_pol` theta function $\sum_n q^{n^2} r^n$  to compute the modular functions, Eisenstein series, j, $\eta$, $\Delta$ @Somos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Euler's formula

$$
\sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} {( - 1)^n q^{\frac{{(3n^2  - n)}}
{2}} }  = \prod\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {(1 - q^n ),}
$$

(which can be proven from Jacobi’s triple product identity by using the fact that $\prod\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {(1 - q^{3n} )(1 - q^{3n - 2} )} (1 - q^{3n - 1} ) = \prod\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {(1 - q^n )}
$)
provides a good way of numerically computing

$$
\eta (\tau )=e^{\frac {\pi {\rm {{i}\tau }}}{12}}\prod _{n=1}^{\infty }(1-e^{2n\pi {\rm {{i}\tau }}})=q^{\frac {1}{24}}\prod _{n=1}^{\infty }(1-q^{n}).
$$

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

My maple code of Gatteschi-Sokal algorithm for computing $R(t,x)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-tx^n)$:

GS:=proc(t,x,prec)

local R0, a0, b0, Rn, an, bn, d, c, i, N, r, Rd;

N := 100;

d := 1/2; if d = t*x then d := (1/2)*d end if;

r := evalf$[prec]$(1+d/(1-x));

a0 := 1; b0 := evalf$[prec]$(d/(d-t*x));

R0 := evalf$[prec]$(r*a0+(1-r)*b0);

i := 0;

while i < N do

c := evalf$[prec]$(a0*(d*a0+(1.0-d)*b0));

an := evalf$[prec]$(c/b0);

bn := evalf$[prec]$(c/(x*a0+(1.0-x)*b0));

Rn := evalf$[prec]$(r*an+(1.0-r)*bn);

Rd := evalf$[prec]$(abs(Rn-R0));

if Rd < 10^(-prec) then i := N else

a0 := an; b0 := bn; R0 := Rn; i := i+1 end if;

end do;

return Rn;

end proc;

eta:=(t,prec)->evalf$[prec]$(GS(1,exp($2*Pi*I*t$),prec));

Dedekind_eta := (t, prec)-> evalf$[prec]$(exp($1/12*Pi*I*t$)*eta(t, prec));

---

Test:

t:=0.3*I:

eta(t,40); Dedekind_eta(t,40);

0.8251926470787677741036466781518992636742

0.7628619270903183863013294748250092216042

Almost same with PARI/GP output:

eta(0.3*I,0)=0.82519264707876777410364667815189926367

eta(0.3*I,1)=0.76286192709031838630132947482500922160